# Python - Writing a specific amount of bytes in a Binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct.pack

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I'm fairly new to python and don't fully know the nomenclature so its hard to search for solutions.

I'm trying to write a code that outputs a binary file in specific integer formats, ie a section in 8 bit, followed by 32 bit, etc. More specifically, in STL format; an outline can be read here: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#Binary_STL).

I have tried doing a simple `f.write(struct.pack(DATA))` to produce an output file, however the end result is a corrupted file. STL does have an ASCII version; which I have working. Therefore I assume something is wrong with the binary file generation. I want to use Binary to reduce the file size significantly.

I assume the output code would look something like this*:

```py
import struct
    f = open('cool_filename.stl', 'wb')
    f.write(struct.pack(head, format=UINT8))
    f.write(struct.pack(num, format=UINT32))
    for i in range(0, num):
        f.write(struct.pack(normal, format=REAL32))
        f.write(struct.pack(vert1, format=REAL32))
        f.write(struct.pack(vert2, format=REAL32))
        f.write(struct.pack(vert3, format=REAL32))
        f.write(struct.pack(attr, format=UINT16))
    f.close()
```

Useful links:

[struct.pack docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack)

[format specs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings)

I believe the answer can be found in the latter link above, but I don't really understand how to use it. Following it, I've tried using `struct.pack(I32, DATA)` to format for the unsigned 32 byte sections, and similar code for the rest, but it doesn't work.

*I should note that this doesn't run. The code here to show the format changes

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `struct.pack` should be a string, and the `I` format spec implies 32 bits (size=4 in the table in the docs means 4 bytes, i.e 4*8=32 bits), so to write a single 32-bit unsigned integer (say, 4711) in little-endian byte order, you would do `struct.pack('<I', 4711)`.

Comment: How would you write a float? I tried using `f.write(struct.pack('<f', 3.14159))` however I get `TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be a str or bytes object, not numpy.float64`. From that and your comment, I tried to convert the float to a string, `f.write(struct.pack('32s', str(3.14159)))`, but now I get `struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object`. How do I get that to work?

Comment: Strange; struct.pack('<f', 3.14159) works for me. Are you sure that is exactly what you did?

Comment: Yeah. For some reason, `struct.pack('f', 3.14159)` is working, but the < gives me that error

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviou... can you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example that I can run?